# Read and write NFC tag at once

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible to read/write NFC-tag simultaneously with Android API? 
For example I have the counter in NDEF message and would like to read it, increment and write it back. Or read authentication key and update it.
I can see only one operation as per example.

Answer (score 0):

Android’s [*Near Field Communication* documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html) page states that it is indeed possible.

> Android-powered devices with NFC simultaneously support three main modes of operation:
>
> 1. Reader/writer mode, allowing the NFC device to **read and/or write** passive NFC tags and stickers.
>      . . .

Answer (score 0):

Android will in the default setup automagically read any NDEF message and deliver it to your activity by invoking onNewIntent(..). Your app is then free to write to the tag - and can do so within the within the invokation to onNewIntent(..) or the following call to onResume(..).

Answer (score 0):

i'm note sure if looking for react native for example, but you can do that from once inside a scope of a function that returns you the message and you can write immediately what you want.

The package is this one:
https://github.com/whitedogg13/react-native-nfc-manager

The feature is in the branch (tag-tech) open to discussion and sooner or later will be at master.